# Flatness of projective bundles 

Tags: projective-geometry

Suppose that $p \colon P \to X$ is a projective bundle. Is $p$ an open map ?

Comment: At least over $\mathbb{C}$, any flat map is open, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/41158/are-flat-morphisms-of-analytic-spaces-open

Comment: thanks..
i saw the references, just to be sure, does it also prove in the zariski topology (instead of complex topology)
for the map P-->X over the field of complex numbers.

Answer (score 3):

For any $X,Y$ the projection $X \times Y \to Y$ is an open map. Since being open is a local property you know this holds also for any fiber bundle and in particular any projective bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't any fiber bundle $p: E \to B$ projection an open map? If $e \in E$ belongs to an open $U$, then there is a trivializing neighborhood $V_e$ of $p(e)$ so that $p^{-1}(V_e) \to V_e$ is isomorphic to a projection map $V_e \times F \to V_e$, which is certainly open. Hence $p(U \cap p^{-1}(V_e))$ is open. Since direct images preserve unions, we see that

$$p(U) = p(\bigcup_{e \in U} U \cap p^{-1}(V_e)) = \bigcup_{e \in U} p(U \cap p^{-1}(V_e))$$

is open.