# Reference for flatness in complex-analytic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, cv.complex-variables, arithmetic-geometry, hodge-theory

What is a good reference for **flat** morphisms of complex-analytic spaces? (The book by Grauert and Remmert doesn't treat them).

Topics I'm interested in: openness of flat maps, descent for coherent analytic sheaves.

Comment: The key is that a non-empty complex-analytic space admits points that are Cohen-Macaulay (work locally, using finite maps to a ball of suitable dimension as in the setup of dimension theory in the G-R book). For a flat map and a CM point in a fiber one can make a "locally quasi-finite quasi-section" adapting the slicing argument as in the scheme case. But for a map of complex-analytic spaces, near an isolated point in a fiber it is *finite* after shrinking on source and target. Thus, locally on the base there exists a *finite flat* quasi-section. Then openness and coherent descent are clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A reference for the fact that flat maps are open in the complex-analytic category is Theorem 2.12, p. 180 in

C. Bănică, O. Stănăşilă: *[Algebraic methods in the global theory of complex spaces](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=463470)*.

See also my answer to MO question [41158](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41158/are-flat-morphisms-of-analytic-spaces-open/41163#41163).